# Do I need airport transit visa/ Transit visa or Schengen Visa?

Tags: transit-visas

I am travelling to Toronto From New Delhi on student visa. My travel schedule is

1. Delhi to Madrid (Terminal 1) - 3 H 15 Minutes stop over in Madrid
2. Madrid (Terminal 2) to Lisbon (Terminal 1) - 20 H 10 Minutes stop over in Lisbon
3. Lisbon (Terminal 1) to Toronto

***Do I need any airport transit visa/transit visa or Schengen Visa to Change the terminal.??***

*Also During the stop over I will stay in airport.*

Comment: This is a duplicate question and it will be closed as such. As you have two airports within the Schengen zone you need a Schengen visa. (Not a transit visa as those are only useful for one stop in the Schengen area.)

Comment: Are you really planning to stay 20h10 in the airport, while in transit on a trip that must last close to 40 hours? As you will need a full visa anyway, you should probably explore the possibility of staying the night somewhere...